# Get functions from a compiled file in Lua

Tags: lua

I'm compiling a file using CompileFile and I'm hoping to be able to get a list of functions from the file and be able to calculate the binary bytecode using string.dump and use debug.getupvalue on some of the functions inside of the compiled file.

Comment: I need to be able to do it from inside Lua

Comment: What do you mean by "functions" in "list of functions"?

Answer (score 0):

Try [lbci](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lbci), a Lua bytecode inspector library.